# Execute Python Script from outside sources

Tags: python

I have a python script hosted in github gist for testing purpose.

It simply contain 1 line of code.

```
print "This line will be printed."
```

I name it `print.py`, and here is a [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bunlongheng/36ead076b79595639124fa783557d419/raw/e9ee46a841fd21fc1e29bdd8be1b0300fc091f72/print.py) to it as **Raw** text.

---

I'm wondering if we can executing it without having to download it to our local VM and then run it.

Is it possible to execute it directly base on the link to it ?

Comment: Sure. There are tons of ways to do this. Most of them involve using a Python framework to write an API and then calling that API. Your browser cannot directly execute Python, however.

Comment: I'm looking for a quick way to execute it. I'm not looking to write an API to get this done. I guess, I'll `wget` it, and execute it.

Comment: But that's downloading it? That's exactly what you said you didn't want.

Comment: Ohh really ?? will it store in the directory that ran the curl ?

Comment: No, it doesn't get permanently saved to the file system, it just pipes it into python.

Comment: Ohh okay. Then. I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean execute it *from the command line* (e.g. bash), I'd grab the contents of the page using `curl` and pipe the output to `python`.

```
curl "URL" -s -N | python
```

In your case:

```
$ curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bheng/36ead076b79595639124fa783557d419/raw/e9ee46a841fd21fc1e29bdd8be1b0300fc091f72/print.py -s -N | python
This line will be printed.
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what OP doesn't want? This is downloading the file.

Comment: @MorganThrapp It's downloading it, yes, but only temporarily. I think OP wanted to avoid having to go through the Gist website and downloading the file manually, then `cd`-ing and executing.